# How to override Spring Data MongoDB's MappingContextIsNewStrategyFactory?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is there any way the provided MappingContextIsNewStrategyFactory can be overridden? I want to provide a new IsNewStrategy, which basically would require me to override MappingContextIsNewStrategyFactory.doGetIsNewStrategy().

For the sake of simplicity, the reasons why are beyond this discussion. I do know about the Persistable interface, but it's not what I need.

I want to know how can I provide my custom MappingContextIsNewStrategyFactory so it's registered with the Spring container, and it's used instead of the default one.

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB version 1.13.1.